# How do I access a Background Workers Progress Changed method within a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I'm creating a windows form application in C#. In it's current state, the application is reporting progress, however I have a class design I need to follow. I need to make use of three different static methods within a static class. To my knowledge I can't follow this design. I want to implement MyUtilities.ProcessList() in my do work routine.

As it stands, my (cliffnoted) code is the following:

```
//form load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
}

//calls the BG worker function
private void startWork()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

// update the progress bar
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // update progressbar
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}


//the big crunch work
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    /*
    This isn't my current code, but it should give an idea of my execution and how I currently report progress 
    There is no issues with my existing code in this section, this is just dummy code.
    */
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        percent = (i / 5)
        //20% of the full end task is done.
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent);
    }

    //How do I access the report progress method if I'm in a different class???
    MyUtilities.ProcessList();

}
```

Is there a common solution to this problem? My idea is to create a class just for reporting progress, and pass the reference to each static method... but at the end of the day, I still face the difficulty of reporting it to the GUI!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your BackgroundWorker reference (or a more abstract object as you suggest) as an argument of ProcessList method.

```
MyUtilities.ProcessList(backgroundWorker1);
```

A standard way to do this is to use an [IProgress< T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) but it's generaly used in async code.

You could also make a class instead of a static method and an instance of the class can report Progress using an event.

```
public class ListProcessor
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    public void Process()
    {
        //...code logic
        if (ProgressChanged != null)
            ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(1, this));
    }

}
```

Comment: disregard my last comment, I passed the reference through and it called reportProgress and it worked!I assume it's subscribed to it somehow... Thanks bud!